# No More Vocals Instruments in GarageBand '11?

Tags: garageband

I'm trying to change my voice on Skype using this tutorial http://www.erzsabet.com/mySLSound.html, which I got working with GarageBand '09. However, I just bought GarageBand '11, and there doesn't seem to be any vocals software instrument. Where can I find them, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Vocal Effects in Garageband. Open Garageband and create a voice project:
[image]
Then go to the Info pane in the bottom right hand corner:
[image]
Under Real Instrument>Vocals, you will find all the effects you were looking for.
[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me what version of GarageBand you're using?

Comment: @hkcktk Garageband 6.0.5, which according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GarageBand#History), is Garageband '11

Comment: That's weird. Is Real Instruments the tab that shows up by default? Mine is Software Instruments, and doesn't have vocals. http://imageshack.us/f/221/19144606jd.png/

Comment: No. You need to change the track to a vocal track, then you'll get the Real Instruments tab.

Comment: Oh, funny. I was certain I'd chosen "Voice" when I created my project, but it seems I hadn't. Anyway, problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!